# jQuery ajax context unexpected values

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

Consider the following example of using jQuery's (*v1.8.3*) `ajax()` method while attempting to supply a context.

```
for(var i=0; i<3; i++) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "foo",
    context: i,
    success: function() { console.log(this); }
}
```

Expected output would be 3 `Number` objects, representing `0, 1 and 2` (not necessarily in that order.) In fact, the output to console is 2 `Number` objects, and 1 `Object` object, containing ajax request data.

```
> Number
> Object {url: "foo", isLocal: false, global: true, type: "GET", contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"…}
> Number
```

Why do I not receive 3 `Number` objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a bit of digging in the jQuery v1.8.3 source, I found this:

```
7645 | // Create the final options object
7646 | s = jQuery.ajaxSetup( {}, options ),
7647 | // Callbacks context
7648 | callbackContext = s.context || s,
```

This means whenever the `context` option of an `ajax()` call is falsy, the value assigned to the callback as the `this` context parameter is an object returned by `jQuery.ajaxSetup()`.

Be aware that passing *any* falsy value as a `context` option will result in this behaviour, including `0`, `null` and `""`.

I beleive a small change could remove this ambiguity, and I would lodge a ticket with the jQuery development team, however I don't know if they'll appreciate a backwards incompatible change that breaks half the internet :(

```
callbackContext = s.context !== undefined ? s.context : s
```

Comment: That's a great find, but it doesn't explain why `0` and `2` work in this situation but `1` doesn't...

Comment: Nevermind, the OP pointed out that the order received may not be the order executed...which is true, but I wouldn't have expected that with such a simple example.

Answer (score 1):

Does it help if you try something like this?:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    (function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "foo",
            context: i,
            success: function () {
                console.log(this);
            }
        });
    })(i);
}
```

But going off of what Aesthete discovered, maybe you could convert to a string when defining the `context`, but then convert back to an integer inside of `success`...something like:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "foo",
        context: ""+i,
        success: function () {
            console.log(+this);
        }
    });
}
```

But of course, this only really applies to your code because you're using integers like this. It might not be as easy if you were passing other falsey values.

Comment: +1 because this is how I got around the issue. I still believe that if you pass a context argument, it should be received, and the fallback should only occur when context is undefined (not supplied).

Comment: @Aesthete Oh I definitely agree...I'm not sure why it is the way it is now. I would think they would have the modification you posted (even use `typeof s.context !== "undefined"` instead of `!== undefined`), so I wonder why not.

Comment: It might be an oversight from yester-year. It's probably too late to change that sort of behaviour now.

Answer (score 1):

it tries to bind the success callback with the context ( and converts it as a object) .

So, if you provide a number, then it will bind it like:

```
 var a=12;
 var test = function(){ console.log(this.valueOf())}.bind(a)
 test();
```

you can use Ian's technique for "+this" instead of "this.valueOf()", just that this will also work with strings.

Comment: Well, **a** is always an object, so it doesn't to convert it. I still don't think it's natural behaviour. Thanks for the input though +1.